# Cauchy integral theorem in a Jordan domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-integration

With the Goursat's lemma we can prove the local version of Cauchy integral theorem in a disk: *if $f$ is holomorphic in an open disk $D\subset \mathbb{C}$, then $f$ has a primitive in $D$.* But can we use the same proof if we consider a Jordan domain $int(J)\subset \mathbb{C}$ of the Jordan curve $ J \subset \mathbb{C}$?

We know that the set $\mathbb{C}\setminus int(J)$ is connected, and domain $int(J)$ is path-connected with rectilinear paths, so we can use the Goursat's lemma?

Answer (score 0):

By the Jordan-Schoenfliess theorem, $\textrm{int}(J)$ is simply connected.
As it is also bounded, it is conformally equivalent to the unit disc
by the Riemann mapping theorem. As every holomorphic
function has a primitive in the unit disc, the same is true for
$\textrm{int}(J)$.

Comment: I do know that simply connected domain is the same as Jordan domain. But my question is that can we infer the result with only Jordan curve theorem. It looks very plausible.

Comment: @Hulkster All Jordan by itself tells us is that $U=\textrm{int}(J)$ is a bounded open set. For every holomorphic function there to have a primitive, it is necessary that $U$ be simply connected. The usual proof of Goursat uses convexity (or some weaker form like star-shapedness) that implies simply connectedness.

Comment: Yes, but we use Goursat's lemma to prove Cauchy theorem in an open disk. Can we use the same method in the case of $int(J)$ ?

Comment: @Hulkster That seems unlikely to me. The usual proof of Goursat on the disc relies very much on the geometry of the disc being very simple to describe...

Comment: OK. Thanks for answering.